# Redux toolkit is not being integrated with nextjs 13 app

Tags: redux, next.js, redux-toolkit, react-server-components

My redux toolkit is not working in my nextjs 13 e-commerce app. I also using the technique to wrap  the app with custom 'use-client' provider to provide store.
But app is crashing and giving error here is the screen shot is attached
[Screen shot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4r9zN.png)

Here my code currently I am using

**Layout.jsx**

```
import { Providers } from "./Providers";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import "./globals.css";

export const metadata = {
    title: "Prime Clothing | Purchase on discounted prices",
    description: "Prime Clothing | Purchase on discounted prices",
};
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <body>
                <Providers>
                    <Navbar />
                    <main className="container mt-24">{children}</main>
                </Providers>
            </body>
        </html>
    );
}
```

**store.js**

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import cartSlice from "./cart/cartSlice";
export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        cart: cartSlice,
    },
});
```

**Providers.jsx**

```
"use client";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "@/app/redux-store/store";
export function Providers({ children }) {
    return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>;
}
```

**cartSlice.js**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
const initialState = {
    cart: [],
};
export const cartSlice = createSlice({
    name: "cart",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        addToCart: (state, action) => {
            const item = action.payload;
        },
    },
});
export const { addToCart } = cartSlice.actions;
export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: What’s your Next.js version ?

Comment: next js version 13.3.0 and react version 18.2.0

Comment: The server components isn’t ready/easy option to use. The ssg/ssr hydrations are really advanced topic. If you want to play that game with redux, next-redux-wrapper prolly the best place to start, without it running store on server-sides isn’t really an option…